# Using mod_mono on Solaris 10 - UNIX

Tags: asp.net, unix, mono, apache2, solaris

I'm trying to get / compile / install mod_mono for Apache 2.2.4 on Solaris 10.

Apache Version: Apache/2.2.4 (Unix)

```
[/]# uname -a
SunOS wexch 5.10 Generic_118855-36 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

I have blastwave installed ([blastwave.org](http://www.blastwave.org)), and am a little disappointed that it doesn't have a mod_mono package, or include mod_mono with other packages such as CSWxsp (mono's XSP server)?

Does anyone know how I can get mod_mono working on Solaris.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to go to the [Mono](http://www.go-mono.com)'s website and [download](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) the appropriate sources instead, looking at the Blastwave's site and the [package](http://www.blastwave.org/jir/pkgcontents.ftd?software=mono&style=brief&state=5&arch=sparc), it does appear to be quite quite old!! You could try rooting around mono's ftp site to look for the identical version and see if there's an old archive mod_mono of the same version within the package and just compile it. By the way it should be noted that the Mono version on Blastwave is 1.1.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'm trying your suggestion to download and compile Mono source.